1st Time Banana Flavor
Wow...I just poured by first beer from a batch of Honey Cream Ale I brewed using BRY-97 West Coast Ale yeast. I kegged it a few days ago, and it is a pretty strong banana flavor.
I tried 6 oz or so when I took the FG reading (which was perfect) and didn't notice any banana flavor.
Cold crashed, added gelatin and kegged the next day.
What happened here?
I have brewed approx 32 batches so far, and no banana flavor in any of them.

Welcome to Homebrewing SE!  It's interesting that you didn't notice the flavor when you took the FG.  The yeast also doesn't seem to be likely to output banana flavors, but just to ask, is it possible the fermentation got pretty hot at some point?  I suppose maybe especially that day between the FG reading and kegging?  I suppose it's also worth asking -- is it possible you accidentally bought banana-flavored gelatin?  Also, would this potentially make sense if it was some kind of contamination from whatever was in the keg before this?

Banana flavors are due to a compound known as iso-amyl acetate, which is a fruity ester. Yeast produces it from isoamyl alcohol, which is a "higher" alcohol (also known as fusel alcohol) and undesirable in beer. The main two factors in producing it are yeast genetics (some strains, especially ale strains, produce more than others - Fermentis BE-256 comes to mind) and fermentation temperature. The latter is probably the biggest factor in your case. Keeping the fermentation temperature down to the lower end of the range specified for your yeast should solve the problem.
Once produced there is no way to get rid of the banana flavor.

Fast fermentation towards the end - probably more oxygenation.

This seems sensible, but is a little unclear as-is.  When do you think the additional oxygenation occurred? Maybe during the FG reading?  Also, why would late oxygenation result in banana flavor?  Are you assuming the temperature is higher than during initial fermentation, or is there something about late fermentation that might cause that?
Or are you saying more oxygenation is required upfront to make sure fermentation occurs toward the beginning?
